# Docker ip for windows

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core

I'm testing out Docker with a basic .NET core project. I Build and image from this docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/API

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

CMD ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://*:5000"]
```

I run it and it goes flawlessly. Now the only problem is, on what IP is it running ?

I'm running Docker on Windows!

Regards

Comment: Are you running "Docker for Windows" or "Docker Toolbox for Windows"? if it is Docker Toolbox, the default ip address should be 192.168.99.100, you should be able to see it when you start docker shell, otherwise the ip address should be same as your local machine.

Comment: Hi! I'm running docker for windows. So you mean the actual IP of my PC, not default / ipv4, but the one I get from e.g. myipchicken or something :) ?

Comment: @Takahiro neither my localhost, default, ipv4 nor public ip is working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're already exposing the port internally, so the only other thing I can suggest is to check you are opening the port when launching your image too:

`docker run -it -p 5000:5000 <imagename>`

This will open port 5000 inside the instance to port 5000 on your local machine, and should then be accessible on `127.0.0.1:5000` or `localhost:5000`.

You should also ensure that you are accepting any host name within `Main()` in `Program.cs` with `.UseUrls("http://*:5000/")` on your `WebHostBuilder`.

Answer (score 12):

I had some issues with running linux containers built for dotnet asp.net core 2 on docker for windows.

The command I was using to run my container was:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 3394:3394 --name <name> <container>
```

I could shell to the container and verify the app was listening and returning results.

However, trying to access the app from my machine on port 3394 wouldn't work for `127.0.0.1`, `localhost`, or my machine's NAT ip on the network.

However, running this command gives the IP address allocated by the docker host:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" <name>
```

In my case the IP was `172.17.0.2`. However, accessing `172.17.0.2:3394` still didn't work.

The last piece needed was to run the following in an elevated dos prompt:

```
route /P add 172.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.0.75.2
```

This added a route so my machine didn't seek the address via my WAN, which was diagnosed via `tracert`.

Credit goes to https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221

Comment: I did as you said still unable to access my httpd container on `172.17.0.2:5555`

Comment: @SlimenTN what is returned by docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" <name>

Comment: it's ok it's working now when I disabled WAMP I was able to access the container via `http://localhost:5555`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to exposed the container port via the docker machine IP address:

```
docker-machine ip
```

In my case this was `192.168.99.100`

So for my mysql container (`docker run -d -p 3306:33060 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql:5.7`)
So I was able to connect via `192.168.99.100:33060`

Answer (score 0):

Run Following command to spin up the MYSQL Instance using docker

Local Directory mounted `E:\docker\mysql-db` to `/var/lib/mysql` . Before running this command make sure to make a local directory & pass it next to -v for the mount

```
docker run --name mysql-server -p 3306:3306 -v E:\docker\mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql -e 
MYSQL_DATABASE=testcase -e MYSQL_USER=testuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=testuser123 -e 
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root123 -d mysql:latest --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation- 
server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

As per docker official docs for mysql. This command is for the first time setup as it involves password and username. After setting up your container first time you can directly spin up the container next time.

You can now connect to your db using above creds in the command.

Check here : https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql