# What is the IP address generated by the Windows container?

Tags: .net, docker

When I create a Docker file in Visual Studio and launch it; the following happens:

If it is a Windows container then when I run the application (with docker-compose as the startup project), then it launches: http://172.22.15.37/ (IP address changes each time).

**What is this IP address and why can I browse to it when using a Windows container, but not a Linux container?** I cannot find it using ipconfig.

The reason I ask is because this does not appear to happen with the Linux container, which browses straight to the local port: http://localhost:30500.

It confuses me even more when I create a Linux container in Visual Studio and run the following command: `docker-inspect {container name}`.   Here I can find the IP address of the container.  When using a windows container I can browse to this IP address on port 80, however when using a Linux container I cannot browse on port 80.

I have spent several hours Googling this, however I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

The allocation of container IP addresses in **Windows** is **different** from the allocation container IP addresses in **Linux**.
In Docker for Windows, the container communicates through a vEthernet adapter called **DockerNAT**.

Please run `ipconfig` in `cmd` at try to find `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT)`.

From version 18.03, you can use DNS name `host.docker.internal`, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host.

I think, the following lecture will be helpful for you:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221

[Docker ip for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709354/docker-ip-for-windows)