# Unable to access .net core api URL after hosting in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, windows-10

I have VS 2017. Dotnet core 2.1
Mine is Windows 10 and Docker for windows installed.
Windows version is 10.0.16299.904
Docker version is community 18.09.0 for both client and server

I simply created a new File-> New-> Project -> .Net Core -> Asp.net Core Web Application -> Api with Docker checkbox enabled.

Without making any change I build it tried run it in IIS Express and Docker and it worked showing /api/values controller response by default as Values.

Now on ps prompt I can see the image and so created the corresponding container.

On docker ps -a command it list the running container with port 1598-> 80/tcp

I used docker inspect  to list json and ip shown is 172.22.74.213.

I used http://172.22.74.213:1598/api/values to access my api but getting below error:

[image]

Using docker inspect says container as running.
Am I using wrong URL to access my api?

Comment: have you tried with localhost:1598?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are using the wrong IP. Just hit `http://localhost:1598/api/values` since Docker for Windows doesn't (default) bind to a different IP for exposed ports.

### Edit

Also, make sure you are actually exposing the port when you run the container. Also check out the details about dotnet APIs allowing any hostname to connect from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715363/4362829):

> check you are opening the port when launching your image too:
>
> `docker run -it -p 5000:5000 <imagename>`
>
> This will open port 5000 inside the instance to port `5000` on your
>   local machine, and should then be accessible on `127.0.0.1:5000` or
>   `localhost:5000`.
>
> You should also ensure that you are accepting any host name within
>   `Main()` in `Program.cs` with `.UseUrls("http://*:5000/")` on your
>   `WebHostBuilder`.

In your case you will need this port binding: `1598:80`.

Comment: Dic you mean http://localhost:1598 or http://localhost:1598/api/values/. I tried both it in chrome browser.

Comment: I meant with the path on the end, so `http://localhost:1598/api/values`. Did this work?

Comment: I tried both these url in chrome browser.  It keep showing loading and does not occur.

Comment: docker run -d --restart=always -p 1598:80 webapplication1

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231001/4362829), which may have something to do with your issue. I am not entirely sure about the details.

Comment: Tried route command suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709354/docker-ip-for-windows/41715363#41715363 on elevated cmd. It returned Ok. Also tried docker run -it -p 5000:5000 <imagename>. Again checked url http://localhost:5000/api/values  still same issue

Comment: You would need to change the ports for that though, unless that was the problem: the port configuration. Could you include the output in your post from running `docker run -it -p 1598:80 <imagename>`?

Answer (score 3):

This is related with the image which is build by `VS 2017`.

Try to build your own image by

```
D:\xx\TestPro>docker build -f DockerTestPro/dockerfile -t docker0115 .
```

And then run container by

```
docker run -it -p 8066:80 docker0115
```

Then, access by `http://localhost:8066/`